# How to keep particular views ember rendered?

Tags: ember.js

I've created tabs for application module which have sizable amount of html tags to render. Views for routes are rendered every time user change submodule.

```
example.com/module/tab
example.com/module/other-tab
example.com/module/different-tab
```

User is going to switch between those tabs a lot, I guess. In this case I would like to keep then in DOM. I mean hide and show on transitions in this particular module instead of removing from dom and rerender. It's like google spreadsheet when you change sheets. First time it's loading then switching immediately.

I manged to hide rendered view on transition by

```
App.ModuleTab = Ember.View.extend
    destroy: ->
        @.$().hide().addClass('module-tab')
```

but **how can I display hidden view instead of rerendering**? Should I modify somehow render method?

Comment: The difference between rerendering and somehow restoring/unhiding existing DOM is likely to be on the order of less than 100ms. If you really care about that, then @Andrew Hacking's answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably want to implement stateful tabs using Ember `queryParams` instead of using routes as the normal route transition will result in the views under your `module` route being torn down.  Ember queryParams have been in beta and canary builds of Ember for a while and have just landed in the official Ember v1.7.0 release 10 days ago.

For a good example/solution for implementing tabs using `queryParams` I would suggest looking at [ic-tabs](http://instructure.github.io/ic-tabs/query-params.html) or the [Ember component project](http://indexiatech.github.io/ember-components/#/overview) for some good examples.

If your tabs contain complex views and need separate controllers, you can achieve this by using the `render` helper for the content of each tab:

`{{render 'module/tab-xx'}}`

Ember will look for a template in `module/tab-xx' and a controller named `ModuleTabXXController` which it will instantiate and bind the view to. See the [Ember guides on rendering views with helpers](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/)

You can then further conditionalize the render if you want to only render when the tab is visible. eg:

```
  {{#ic-tabs selected-index=country}}
    {{#ic-tab-list}}
      {{#ic-tab}}Australia{{/ic-tab}}
      {{#ic-tab}}United Kingdom{{/ic-tab}}
      {{#ic-tab}}USA{{/ic-tab}}
    {{/ic-tab-list}}

    {{#ic-tab-panel}}
      {{#if active}}
         {{render 'country/au' auModel}}
      {{/if}}
    {{/ic-tab-panel}}

    {{#ic-tab-panel}}
      {{#if active}}
         {{render 'country/uk' ukModel}}
      {{/if}}
    {{/ic-tab-panel}}

    {{#ic-tab-panel}}
      {{#if active}}
         {{render 'country/us' usModel}}
      {{/if}}
    {{/ic-tab-panel}}

  {{/ic-tabs}}
```

Comment: I will check `queryParams` in couples minutes but beforehand I have one question. Will I have to render all the modules at once? Each of them is rendering approximately 1 sec so I strongly dislike the idea of rendering multiple modules at the same time. Moreover I want to keep my code logic structure. One large controller is not a optimum option.

Comment: Updated answer to address additional requirements.

Answer (score -1):

You should override the [createElement](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#method_createElement) method, and check if element already exists and hidden.

```
App.ModuleTab = Ember.View.extend
  createElement: ->
    if @get 'element'
      @.$().show()
      @
    else @._super.createElement()
  destroy: ->
    @.$().hide().addClass('module-tab')
```

Comment: It is not working. Ember is adding new element to dom and keep old either.

Comment: @estshy Oh ok, you can't do it with an Ember.View, because when destroy is called, Ember.View instance is gone. So when a new view is rendered a new Ember.View instance gets created, which has no idea about the old one, so if you really want hack, use `$('module-tab-and-other-specific-selector-for-the-old-tab')` instead of `@get 'element'`. Hope you get my idea.

Comment: Even with unique selector and `if $('#some-unique-id').length` ember still rerender view.

Comment: @estshy I am not familiar with the Ember.View API, i guessed this method would be responsible for dom creation, feel free to experiment with other methods and use the appropriate one. I guess you can test it by overriding it to do nothing. Sorry for the inconvenience, and accept if you happen to find a solution.

Comment: I guess that I have to overwrite some upon module (like router) to get this to work but I am not familiar with ember api either. Moreover, thanks for your time.